# "insufficient privileges" error in service Cloud Console

Tags: servicecloud

When I accept chat request `insufficient privileges` error comes. As per other community suggestions I checked for agent permission and found these permissions enabled:

1. Customize Application
2. View Setup and Configuration
3. Live agent User.

Neither I have customized chat widow. Please suggest what may be the cause and how to get it resolved.

Comment: Intermittent or does it happen all the time?